# Date format on mobile version

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

Currently I have problem on setting up a date formate on my mobile application using Jquery mobile with HTML5. The problem is that on

```
<input type="date" id="start_date" name="start_date" />
```

- Native Android browser displays
  12/30/2013
- Chrome browser on Android displays 12/30/2013
- Safari browser displays 
  Dec 30, 2013
- Firefox on android displays
  2013-12-30

So i do wanna know if there is a way to set the standard date format m/d/yy so those browser so they will use that format?.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways unfortunately.

- Chrome for Android follows desktop Chrome, which prefer digits because it provides keyboard input capability.
- Mobile Safari shows dates in a readable format. It doesn't need to take care of keyboard input.
- Firefox doesn't support localization of type=date. It's a bug.